# JavaScript: Is this timer reliable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, web-worker

Today I was introduced to the world of Web Workers in JavaScript. This made me rethink about timers. I used to program timers the ugly way, like this.

```
var time = -1;
function timerTick()
{
    time++;
    setTimeout("timerTick()",1000);
    $("#timeI").html(time);
}
```

I know this could be improved by saving the date when you start the timer, but I've never been a fan of that.

Now I came up with a method using Web Workers, I did a little benchmark and found it much more reliable. Since I am not an expert on JavaScript I would like to know if this function works correct or what problems it might have thanks in advance.

My JavaScript code (please note I use JQuery):

```
$(function() {
    //-- Timer using web worker. 
    var worker = new Worker('scripts/task.js'); //External script
    worker.onmessage = function(event) {    //Method called by external script
        $("#timeR").html(event.data)
    };
};
```

The external script ('scripts/task.js'):

```
var time = -1;
function timerTick()
{
    time++;
    setTimeout("timerTick()",1000);
    postMessage(time);
}
timerTick();
```

You can also view a live demo on [my website](http://daan.hostei.com/hm/timer/).

Comment: `setInterval` is not very reliable.

Comment: Don't pass a string to `setTimeout` or `setInterval`. Always use an explicit function reference or anonymous function: `setTimeout(timerTick)` or `setTimeout(function() { timerTick(123); } )`

Comment: @Kenaniah: That's not a good idea. At least with `setTimeout`, you could test for fluctuation in the timing, and adjust the next call.

Comment: @pimvdb Why is it not reliable?  The only shortcoming I can think of is that it isn't gauranteed to fire after the interval if other JS is already running (in the same context).  But setTimeout has the same problem.

Comment: @Matt I think (well, I hope :-) that his point was that *none* of the timing options in a browser are reliable.

Comment: @Matt: That's what I mean; `setInterval` does not seem to be a solution to the OP's problem.

Comment: No setInterval() will continue to schedule on the interval even if something is blocking. Which is almost always a bad thing because eventually the app will back up.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're trying to reliably display seconds ticking by, then the ONLY reliable way to do that is to get the current time at the start and use the timer ONLY for updating the screen.  On each tick, you get the current time, compute the actual elapsed seconds and display that.  Neither `setTimeout()` nor `setInterval()` are guaranteed or can be used for accurately counting time.

You can do it like this:

```
var start = +(new Date);
setInterval(function() {
    var now = +(new Date);
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = Math.round((now - start)/1000);
}, 1000);
```

If the browser gets busy and timers are erratically spaced, you may get a slightly irregular update on screen, but the elapsed time will remain accurate when the screen is updated.  Your method is susceptible to accumulating error in the elapsed time.

You can see this work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Gfwze/

Comment: Nice code! I never saw this coded that short and simple. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Uhm, I know that it's kind of late to answer that but I want to point out that the code above might not actually be precise. You don't get to see it because of Math.round but every interval will be a few milliseconds off. In my opinion it's better to use setTimeout, measure the time difference and have the possibility to adjust for the delay that might happen inside the function.

Comment: When I run your code and I change my system date, it affects the seconds by adding or subtracting the difference in time. Is there a way to make this solution independent of the client's system date?

Comment: @KidDiamond - no, not really for accurate time.  You could (through some elaborate means) probably detect if the system time has been changed by the user (to perhaps prevent cheating at some time dependent operation), but Javascript does not expose a clock that is independent of the time that the user can set (most operating systems have such a clock, but JS doesn't provide access to it).

Comment: See also: this fork of the above jsfiddle which shows the difference. It strays even faster if you alt-tab for a bit. http://jsfiddle.net/mxbbm2L0/1/

Comment: @JamiePate - several browsers are known to "slow" down `setInterval()` calls when the browser tab they are running in is not visible and then "catch them up" when the tab becomes visible again.  See this article: http://blog.pivotal.io/labs/labs/chrome-and-firefox-throttle-settimeout-setinterval-in-inactive-tabs

Comment: Not sure on the 'catch them up' part. In chrome, after 288 seconds it had skewed  by +1.868s and never skews the other way. The point is, you should use timestamps for timing, not increments triggered by an unreliable timer event. (firefox does seem to attempt to catch up, but i still wouldn't trust it, and other browsers have different behavior to boot)

Comment: @JamiePate - There have been reports of fast `setInterval()` calls when the tab becomes foreground again.  I don't see it personally in [this test bed](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/gvakfdd5/) in Chrome now so perhaps that was an older behavior or only in certain conditions or in other browsers.  Now, I just see Chrome and Firefox slowing intervals to only once per second.

Answer (score 0):

The most accurate timer would be a comparison of two time stamps. You could increase the precision of your timer by updating more frequently (such as every 100ms). I prefer using `setInterval()` over `setTimeout()`.