# Javascript setInterval flickering

Tags: javascript, timer, setinterval, clock

I'm trying to create a chess clock using JavaScript. I've settle almost all of the issues with the clock's functionality except for this one. I'm using setInterval to essentially create the "countdown" effect on each player's clock. However, when it is triggered with the method I'm currently using the clock flickers. From my understanding/research, this is likely because there are overlapping 'intervals' that cause the code to try to display multiple intervals at the same time. Essentially the clock buttons (stopclock and stopclock2) when clicked call the functions on the bottom of my code. Could anyone provide some input on my code (below) and why this might be occurring?

```
clear1mils = "";
clear2mils = "";


//Clock Functions
function countdownmils2() {
  document.getElementById("milsvalue2").innerHTML = --mil2;
   if (mil2 == 0) {
    mil2 = mil2 + 59;
     if (sec2 == 0) {
      if (min2 == 0) {
        clearInterval(clear2mils);
        document.getElementById("milsvalue2").innerHTML = "00";
          }else if (min2 !== 0) {
            sec2 = 60;
            document.getElementById("minutesvalue2").innerHTML = --min2;
            document.getElementById("secondsvalue2").innerHTML = --sec2;
            }
     }else if (sec2 !== 0) {
      document.getElementById("secondsvalue2").innerHTML = --sec2;
      if (sec2 <= 10) {
        document.getElementById("secondsvalue2").innerHTML = "0" + sec2;
      }
     }
    }else if (mil2 <= 10) {
      document.getElementById("milsvalue2").innerHTML = "0" + mil2;
     }
    }

function countdownmils() {
  document.getElementById("milsvalue").innerHTML = --mil;
  if (mil == 0) {
    mil = mil + 59;
     if (sec == 0) {
      if (min == 0) {
        clearInterval(clear1mils);
        document.getElementById("milsvalue").innerHTML = "00";
       }else if (min !== 0) {
         sec = 60;
         document.getElementById("minutesvalue").innerHTML = --min;
         document.getElementById("secondsvalue").innerHTML = --sec;
        }
     }else if (sec !== 0) {
       document.getElementById("secondsvalue").innerHTML = --sec;
       if (sec <= 10) {
        document.getElementById("secondsvalue").innerHTML = "0" + sec;
       }
     }
  }else if (mil <= 10) {
    document.getElementById("milsvalue").innerHTML = "0" + mil;
  }
}


//Clock 1
document.querySelector("#stopclock").addEventListener("click", () => {
  clear2mils = setInterval(countdownmils2, 10);
  clearInterval(clear1mils);
  document.getElementById("stopclock").innerHTML = "DOWN";
  document.getElementById("stopclock2").innerHTML = "UP";
  document.getElementById("stopclock").setAttribute("disabled", "true");
  document.getElementById("stopclock2").removeAttribute("disabled", "true");
});

//Clock 2
document.querySelector("#stopclock2").addEventListener("click", () => {
  clear1mils = setInterval(countdownmils, 10);
  clearInterval(clear2mils);
  document.getElementById("stopclock2").innerHTML = "DOWN";
  document.getElementById("stopclock").innerHTML = "UP";
  document.getElementById("stopclock2").setAttribute("disabled", "true");
  document.getElementById("stopclock").removeAttribute("disabled", "true");
});
```

Comment: indent your code to make it readable

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332526/javascript-is-this-timer-reliable) and [this one](https://medium.com/@abhi9bakshi/why-javascript-timer-is-unreliable-and-how-can-you-fix-it-9ff5e6d34ee0)

Comment: I indented the code as best I can and only included what matters here. Essentially there are event listeners on the two buttons I have for each player's clock. Once they are clicked they set the global variables "clear1mils" or "clear2mils" with setInterval. Set Interval uses the countdownmils or countdownmils2 functions at the top of my code.